# Sorting queues elements in linked list in C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, queue

I had my Data Structures Final exam last week. I'm trying to solve one of the question on my exam. I came up with a solution but the code I wrote does not work on my computer. I probably did something wrong.

The question was something like this : There are 2 queues given and we should dequeue elements from those queues and sort them in a linked list.

I came up with an idea. There will be a function which takes 2 queues and the root of a linked list as parameter, and it will dequeue each queue until there is nothing left than starts to dequeue the other one. Linked list has a add function which adds as sorted.

This is the function that dequeues and adds to linked list
`

```
void sortedlist(queue *q1, queue *q2, node *root) {
    while (q1->counter != 0) {
        sortedInsert(root, dequeue(q1));
    }
    while (q2->counter != 0) {
        sortedInsert(root, dequeue(q2));
    }
}
```

`

This is the function to add elements to linked list as sorted.

```
  node* sortedInsert(node *root, int x) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node*));
        root->x = x;
        root->next = NULL;
        return root;
    }
    if (x< root->x) {
        node *temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->next = root;
        temp->x = x;
        return temp;
    }
    node *iter = root;
    while (iter->next != NULL && iter->next->x < x) {
        iter = iter->next;
    }
    node *temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->x = x;
    temp->next = iter->next;
    iter->next = temp;
    return root;
}
```

I will wrote all of the code here. Maybe there are some who can show me where I did wrong. Thanks in advance for your consideration.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100
//there are 2 queues, and one empty linked list
//take elements from queues and sort it on linked list

struct q {
    int queue[MAX];
    int front;
    int rear;
    int counter;
};

struct node {
    int x;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node node;
typedef struct q queue;


void enqueue(queue *queue, int x) {

    if (!(queue->counter == MAX)) {
        queue->rear++;
        queue->counter++;
        if (queue->rear == MAX)
            queue->rear = 0;
        queue->queue[queue->rear] = x;
    }

}

int dequeue(queue *queue) {

    if (!(queue->counter == 0)) {
        int x = queue->queue[queue->front];
        queue->counter--;
        queue->front++;
        if (queue->front == MAX)
            queue->front = 0;
        return x;
    }
    else 
        return - 1;
}

node* sortedInsert(node *root, int x) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node*));
        root->x = x;
        root->next = NULL;
        return root;
    }
    if (x< root->x) {
        node *temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->next = root;
        temp->x = x;
        return temp;
    }
    node *iter = root;
    while (iter->next != NULL && iter->next->x < x) {
        iter = iter->next;
    }
    node *temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->x = x;
    temp->next = iter->next;
    iter->next = temp;
    return root;
}

void printlist(node *root) {

    while (root != NULL) {
        printf("%d \n", root->x);
        root = root->next;
    }
}

void initialize(queue *queue) {
    queue->counter = 0;
    queue->front = 0;
    queue->rear = -1;
}

void sortedlist(queue *q1, queue *q2, node *root) {
    while (q1->counter != 0) {
        sortedInsert(root, dequeue(q1));
    }
    while (q2->counter != 0) {
        sortedInsert(root, dequeue(q2));
    }
}

int main(void) {

    queue *q1 = NULL, *q2 = NULL;
    node *root = NULL;
    initialize(q1);
    initialize(q2);

    enqueue(q1, 10);
    enqueue(q1, 20);
    enqueue(q1, 30);
    enqueue(q1, 40);
    enqueue(q1, 50);
    enqueue(q1, 60);
    enqueue(q1, 70);
    enqueue(q2, 15);
    enqueue(q2, 25);
    enqueue(q2, 35);
    enqueue(q2, 45);
    enqueue(q2, 55);
    enqueue(q2, 65);
    enqueue(q2, 75);
    enqueue(q2, 85);
    enqueue(q2, 95);
    enqueue(q2, 105);
    enqueue(q2, 115);

    sortedlist(q1, q2, root);
    printlist(root);
}
```

Comment: Just use `gdb` to highlight the step where you have an issue

Comment: you never use the returned value, looks to be the major issue

Comment: It's hard to find the error if you don't tell how it goes wrong.

Comment: I do apologize, I am super new to StackOverflow. I'll use gdb and be more specific about the issue in my code. It was 2 in the morning when I posted this. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 0):

Actually very little had to change to make this program function.

First, let's look how you are initializing your queues:

```
queue *q1 = NULL, *q2 = NULL;
node *root = NULL;
initialize(q1);
initialize(q2);
```

You're creating and initializing to NULL two queue pointers.   Then initialize them like so:

```
void initialize(queue *queue) {
    queue->counter = 0;
    queue->front = 0;
    queue->rear = -1;
}
```

This cannot work (and immediately segfaulted for me) because you're passing NULL pointers into that function and then attempting to set values on it (`NULL->counter = 0`, ...).

There a lots of ways to do this but one might be like  this:

```
/* Allocate a queue and initialize it */
queue *createQueue(void) {
    queue *q = malloc(sizeof(*q));
    q->counter = 0;
    q->front = 0;
    q->rear = -1;
    return q;
}

/* In your main() */
queue *q1 = createQueue();
queue *q2 = createQueue();
node *root = NULL;
```

Next let's look at beginning of your `sortedInsert` function and how you call it:

```
node* sortedInsert(node *root, int x) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node*));
        root->x = x;
        root->next = NULL;
        return root;
    }
    /* ... */
    return root;
}

void sortedlist(queue *q1, queue *q2, node *root) {
    while (q1->counter != 0) {
        sortedInsert(root, dequeue(q1));
    }
    while (q2->counter != 0) {
        sortedInsert(root, dequeue(q2));
    }
}
```

There are two problems here.  First, in `sortedInsert` you are `malloc`ing memory for a `node*` (a pointer to the struct) but you want to malloc for `node` (the struct itself).

Also, you never use the returned `node*` so it will be NULL every time.  I would retool this more but in the interests of making minimal changes this will work:

```
/* The proper allocation in sortedInsert */
node* sortedInsert(node *root, int x) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    /* ... */

    /* Store the return value each time, *and* return root from here */
    node *sortedlist(queue *q1, queue *q2) {
        node *root = NULL;

        while (q1->counter != 0) {
            root = sortedInsert(root, dequeue(q1));
        }
        while (q2->counter != 0) {
            root = sortedInsert(root, dequeue(q2));
        }

        return root;
    }
```

Finally it's always good practice to clean up your allocations, so do that after you print the list:

```
/* New function to free your list elements */
void freelist(node *root) {
    node *tmp;

    while (root) {
        tmp = root->next;
        free(root);
        root = tmp;
    }
}

/* The end of your main() */
root = sortedlist(q1, q2);
printlist(root);
freelist(root);
free(q1);
free(q2);
```

If you plan on doing more work in C it's invaluable to use debuggers (gdb, VisualStudio, etc), and tools like valgrind.

Here is a link to the modified working program if the above is hard to follow: [gist](https://gist.github.com/michael-grunder/91e6feb84b1b760b7a2abc87ea4280fc)

Comment: I really appreciate it. Thank you very much for your help. I'll use debuggers ! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue was that you were passing pointers into the functions as arguments with no return value - if you're not passing a **pointer to a pointer** then what the actual pointer points to won't be changed. I changed your code to the below and it ran fine for me when playing with it in ideone.com

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100
//there are 2 queues, and one empty linked list
//take elements from queues and sort it on linked list

struct q {
   int queue[MAX];
   int front;
   int rear;
   int counter;
};

struct node {
    int x;
   struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node node;
typedef struct q queue;


void enqueue(queue **queue, int x) {

    if (!((*queue)->counter == MAX)) {
        (*queue)->rear++;
        (*queue)->counter++;
        if ((*queue)->rear == MAX)
            (*queue)->rear = 0;
        (*queue)->queue[(*queue)->rear] = x;
    }

}

 int dequeue(queue **queue) {

    if (!((*queue)->counter == 0)) {
        int x = (*queue)->queue[(*queue)->front];
        (*queue)->counter--;
        (*queue)->front++;
        if ((*queue)->front == MAX)
            (*queue)->front = 0;
        return x;
    }
    else 
        return - 1;
}

node* sortedInsert(node **root, int x) {
    if (*root == NULL) {
        *root = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node*));
        (*root)->x = x;
        (*root)->next = NULL;
        return root;
    }
    if (x< (*root)->x) {
        node *temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->next = root;
        temp->x = x;
        return temp;
    }
    node *iter = *root;
    while (iter->next != NULL && iter->next->x < x) {
        iter = iter->next;
    }
    node *temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->x = x;
    temp->next = iter->next;
    iter->next = temp;
    return *root;
}

void printlist(node *root) {

    while (root != NULL) {
        printf("%d \n", root->x);
        root = root->next;
    }
}

void initialize(queue **q) {
    *q = (queue*)malloc(sizeof(queue));
    (*q)->counter = 0;
    (*q)->front = 0;
    (*q)->rear = -1;
}

void sortedlist(queue **q1, queue **q2, node **root) {
    while ((*q1)->counter != 0) {
        sortedInsert(root, dequeue(q1));
    }
    while ((*q2)->counter != 0) {
        sortedInsert(root, dequeue(q2));
    }
}

int main(void) {
printf("hello\n");

    queue *q1 = NULL, *q2 = NULL;
    node *root = NULL;
    initialize(&q1);
    initialize(&q2);
printf("init\n");
    enqueue(&q1, 10);
    enqueue(&q1, 20);
    enqueue(&q1, 30);
    enqueue(&q1, 40);
    enqueue(&q1, 50);
    enqueue(&q1, 60);
    enqueue(&q1, 70);
    enqueue(&q2, 15);
    enqueue(&q2, 25);
    enqueue(&q2, 35);
    enqueue(&q2, 45);
    enqueue(&q2, 55);
    enqueue(&q2, 65);
    enqueue(&q2, 75);
    enqueue(&q2, 85);
    enqueue(&q2, 95);
    enqueue(&q2, 105);
    enqueue(&q2, 115);
printf("queued\n");
    sortedlist(&q1, &q2, &root);
printf("sorted\n");
    printlist(root);
}
```